# Why do dynamic colors from my colors catalogue do not work on my navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-darkmode

I am assigning a custom color from my *Colors.xcassets* (that has two color values, one for light, one for dark mode) to my navigation bar using this method:

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: ...;`.

For some reason the navigation bar only takes the color value for the dark mode, even when the application launches in, or switches to light mode. It always uses the darker blue tint:

[image]

When I set this color to other objects, it works just as it should work. As I found no thread describing this problem, I am quite clueless about how I can solve this. It happens in both, iOS13 and iOS14.

Thanks in advance,

Bastian

Answer (score -1):

Create two colors, say `navTint` and `navBack` and set them as follows. Note I set them to the navigationbar as well as the toolbar.

```
    UINavigationController * nav          = ... whatever your nav controller may be ...;

    nav.navigationBar.tintColor           = [UIColor colorNamed:@"navTint"];
    nav.navigationBar.barTintColor        = [UIColor colorNamed:@"navBack"];
    nav.toolbar.tintColor                 = [UIColor colorNamed:@"navTint"];
    nav.toolbar.barTintColor              = [UIColor colorNamed:@"navBack"];
```

Comment: The question is about dark mode, your answer doesn't seem to target this.

Comment: Those colors - ```navTint``` and ```navBack``` - will have a dark mode variation.

Comment: The way OP does it should work and I don't think it is a dark mode issue. OP of course only sets tint of bar while my suggestion properly sets tint of bar and items. I think here I am trying to show OP how to properly and fully set the colours rather than trying to figure out how iOS fades and changes OPs colours between dark and light mode, hoping that that will solve issue or at least help in right direction - but never heard if it worked for OPs colours ...